# How to get max open?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to get the highest open between day, week and month.
So far I have success when I'm on daily but when intraday, it is not showing correctly the highest open, but only today's open.
Can anyone please help me get it to work correctly on intraday?
Here's the code handling that:

```
dopen = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open, barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
wopen = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
mopen = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

maxOpen = max(highest(security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open, barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on), dayofweek-1), wopen, mopen)
plot(onePlot and maxOpen ? maxOpen : na, title="Highest Open", color= maxOpen != maxOpen[1] ? na : color.new( color.green, 0), style=plot.style_line,linewidth = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following algorithm for the intraday bars.

- Have a `var` that keeps track of the highest open price
- Reset this variable when it is a new day
- If the current bar's open price is bigger than this variable, update its value

Code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var highest_open = 10e-10

is_new_day = dayofweek[1] != dayofweek

if (is_new_day)
    highest_open := open
else
    if (open > highest_open)
        highest_open := open

bgcolor(is_new_day ? color.new(color.blue, 80) : na)
plot(highest_open, "Open", color.green, 2, plot.style_circles)
```

[image]